# convert date format from mm/dd/yyyy to yyy/mm/dd in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a date format of `mm/dd/yyyy` I need to convert into `yyyy/mm/dd`

```
 published_date = self.clean(published_dateformat).split('at')[0]
 new_published_date = datetime.date.strftime(published_date,"%Y/%m/%d")
```

Comment: this is not [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please provide `published_dateformat`

Comment: published_dateformat =7/11/2019 at 7.09pm so split function will remove at 7.09pm so finally published_date will be 7/11/2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
from datetime import datetime
published_dateformat = "7/11/2019 at 7.09pm"
published_date = published_date = (published_dateformat).split('at')[0][:-1]
published_date = datetime.strptime(published_date,"%d/%m/%Y")
new_published_date = published_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")
```

With this, `new_published_date` will have value of `'2019/11/07'`

Comment: data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  I get this error

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what was your input? This does not output an error for me, so either you have a different input or it might be because of different Python version. If you tell me which line threw this error I can help

Comment: published_dateformat = self.clean(raw_published_date).split('.')[0]
            published_date = self.clean(published_dateformat).split('at')[0]
            published_date = (datetime.strptime(published_date,'%m/%d/%Y'))
            new_published_date = published_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

raw_publlished date = 7/11/2019 at 7.09pm.this incluses ***
this im splitng wth . thn wth at

Comment: @kprcse your last comment is unreadable. Also, if this word is outputting an error in your terminal, you probably don't have the same input. Please provide your **exact** input so I can adjust the answer properly.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this like this.

```
from datetime import datetime
published_dateformat = "7/11/2019 at 7.09pm"
published_date = (published_dateformat).split('at')[0][:-1]
print(datetime.strptime(published_date,'%d/%m/%Y').strftime("%Y/%m/%d"))
```

Comment: data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  i get this error

Comment: can you please specify the line getting this error?

Comment: published_dateformat = self.clean(raw_published_date).split('.')[0]
            published_date = self.clean(published_dateformat).split('at')[0]
            published_date = (datetime.strptime(published_date,'%m/%d/%Y'))
            new_published_date = published_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

raw_publlished date = 7/11/2019 at 7.09pm.this incluses ***
this im splitng wth . thn wth at

Comment: Kindly can you tell me what you are doing in self.clean()? may be that's exhibiting this error

Comment: remove the function clean and then execute my code with your input

Comment: published_dateformat = (raw_published_date).split('.')[0]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
I face this remove wen I removed clean

Comment: ''.join(raw_published_date)split('.')[0] try this